# Record video from browser to server

Tags: flash, red5, record, rtmp

I'm looking to record video from a user's browser to the web server. We've already got a working Red5 server up. I'm in need of details how to configure the server to store the video somewhere on disk, as well as a browser frontend to complete this.

Also, I'd like to have a way to update the mysql database when the recording is finished, if that is even feasible.

Need more info? Just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to be honest, i have never worked with red5, and it's a little too big to find the right entrypoint right now ...

you might wanna take a look at [haxevideo](http://haxevideo.org/) (you'll need [Haxe](http://haxe.org) for that ... it's much smaller, and you can simply hook yourself into `RealtimeServer::clientRead`, to copy the data to any location you want it ...

Comment: haxevideo looks very promising. Even if it doesn't work atm for me :) Seems to be problems with Flash Player 10

Answer (score 0):

Red 5 can handle video recording out of the box, it needs no special config.

For the frontend video recording client you can use [HDFVR](https://hdfvr.com/) which is specifically made to record through Red5.

Red5 1.0.7 has the best video recording implementation so far.

Disclaimer: I'm part of the team that developed HDFVR and I've also worked on Red5 fixing/patching 2 big video recording bugs ([one](https://hdfvr.com/blog/recording-high-quality-hd-video-over-slow-connections-with-red5-is-now-possible/), [two](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/issues/154)).